# how to align item horizontally in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

i've been stuck for hours just to align an item vertically and horizontally in v-card. this image below is what i currently have, i just have to align the item vertically but i dont know how. can anyone help me? thanks in advance

[image]

My code :

```
<div class="pt-3">
        <v-card class="pa-3">
            <v-row align="center" justify="center" v-bind:style="{ height: deviceHeight * 0.6 + 'px',}">
                <v-col class="fill-height" height="500">
                    <v-card class="text-center grey" height="100%">
                        <div align="center" justify="center">
                            <v-icon>mdi-camera</v-icon>
                            <h3>Upload</h3>
                        </div>
                    </v-card>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
        </v-card>
    </div>

computed: {
    deviceHeight(){
        return this.$vuetify.breakpoint.height;
    },
    deviceWidth(){
        return this.$vuetify.breakpoint.width;
    },
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `align` and `justify` props are used for some Vuetify components, but they won't work on a native HTML `div`. Instead use the appropriate classes on the `v-card`...

```
     <v-card class="text-center grey d-flex flex-column align-center justify-center" height="100%">
             <div>
                 <v-icon>mdi-camera</v-icon>
                 <h3>Upload</h3>
             </div>
     </v-card>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/G0PAB4Vfjs)

Answer (score 1):

`v-row` behaves as the `flex-container` and all the props like `justify` or `align` or any flex container property will work to it only. Just change ur `div`  to `v-row`. Althought there is one problem with that is `v-row` have some negative margin which you can rid off by using `no-gutters`

```
<div class="pt-3">
            <v-card class="pa-3">
                <v-row align="center" justify="center" v-bind:style="{ height: deviceHeight * 0.6 + 'px',}">
                    <v-col class="fill-height" height="500">
                        <v-card class="text-center grey" height="100%">
                            <v-row no-gutters align="center" justify="center">
                                <v-icon>mdi-camera</v-icon>
                                <h3>Upload</h3>
                            </div>
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
            </v-card>
        </div>
```